# Allocate a 2d array in C with one dimension fixed

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, malloc

I want to dynamically allocate 1 dimension of a 2D array (the other dimension is given). Does this work:

```
int NCOLS = 20;

// nrows = user input...

double *arr[NCOLS];

arr = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*nrows);
```

and to free it:

```
free(arr)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite -- what you've declared is an array of pointers.  You want a pointer to an array, which would be declared like this:

```
double (*arr)[NCOLS];
```

Then, you'd allocate it like so:

```
arr = malloc(nrows * sizeof(double[NCOLS]));
```

It can then be treated as a normal `nrows` by `NCOLS` 2D array.  To free it, just pass it to `free` like any other pointer.

In C, there's no need to cast the return value of `malloc`, since there's an implicit cast from `void*` to any pointer type (this is not true in C++).  In fact, doing so can mask errors, such as failing to `#include <stdlib.h>`, due to the existence of implicit declarations, so it's discouraged.

The data type `double[20]` is "array 20 of `double`, and the type `double (*)[20]` is "pointer to array 20 of `double`".  The `cdecl(1)` program is very helpful in being able to decipher complex C declarations ([example](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=double+%28%2aarr%29%5B20%5D)).

Comment: Thanks! When I do this, I get the following error: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'double (*)[1]'

Comment: The code I have is: double (*arr)[NCOLS]; struct->arr      = malloc(sizeof(double[NCOLS]) * nrows);

Comment: @user308827: Are you compiling it as C code or C++?  If it's C, there's no need for the cast, as I said above, if you're compiling it as C++, then you need to cast the result.  In this case, you'd cast it to `(double (*)[NCOLS])`.

Answer (score 1):

An example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COLS 2

void func(int (**arr)[COLS], int rows)
{
    int i, j;

    *arr = malloc(sizeof(int[COLS]) * rows);
    printf("Insert number: \n"); 
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) 
            scanf("%d", &(*arr)[i][j]);
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
        for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) 
            printf("%d\n", (*arr)[i][j]);
}


int main(void)
{ 
    int (*arr)[COLS];

    func(&arr, 2);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try to run this program, I get the error: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int (*)[2]' How do I rectify that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate a new array for each element (each element is a pointer to an array) on the first dimension. You can use a loop for that:

```
for(i = 0; i < NCOLS; i++)
   arr[i] = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*nrows);
```

Do the same to free.