# How to create and return a 2D matrix from a function in C using malloc?

Tags: c, matrix, malloc, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to send a file to a function that creates a matrix of a struct called Entry, populates it based on the file, and returns the matrix.  Right now it's a cascade of errors that I can add if needed, but I suspect I'm just making multiple dumb errors.  If there's an easier way that doesn't involve malloc, that would work just as well.

What am I doing wrong and how can I do this properly?

Here's the relevant code:

```
Entry **matCreate(FILE *fp){

// initialize matrix
Entry matrix = malloc(states * N_CC * sizeof(Entry));

// populate the matrix with initial values
for (int i = 0; i < states; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < N_CC; j++) {
    matrix[i][j].next = 99;
    matrix[i][j].action = "D";
  }
}
return matrix;
}
```

and in the main function:

```
Entry **matrix = matCreat(fp);
```

---

I'm starting the function off with

```
Entry **matCreate(FILE *fp){
```

Initializing it with

```
Entry (*matrix)[N_CC] = malloc( states * sizeof *matrix );
```

Populating it with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < states; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < N_CC; j++) {
    matrix[i][j].next = 99;
    matrix[i][j].action = "D";
  }
}
```

And getting it from main with:
    Entry ourMat = (*matCreate(fp))[N_CC];

But still getting the error:
    tokenize.c:84:1: warning: return from incompatible pointer type     [enabled by default]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: is N_CC known at compile time?

Comment: Yes, it's a constant defined in the header file.

Comment: `Entry **` is not compatible with a 2D array; which do you want?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295318/allocate-a-2d-array-in-c-with-one-dimension-fixed

Comment: @CarlNorum the term "2D array" can be used to describe an array of pointers to the first element of arrays

Comment: @MattMcNabb, that's not a 2D array; in C a 2D array is an array of arrays.

Comment: A 2D array, please.  I think that's the source of the last error I'm trying to figure out.  What should the declaration for matCreate look like?

Comment: @CarlNorum it has 2 dimensions and each dimension is an array, so it is a 2D array. You seem to be arbitrarily defining terminology.

Comment: @Rohawk `Entry **matCreate(FILE *fp)` is the syntax for returning a jagged array. However `Entry (*matrix)[N_CC]` etc. is for allocating an array of arrays. You have to pick which of those two things you want, you can't mix and match. (C doesn't have a "native" multidimensional array).   My post covers the array of arrays topic, RADAR's covers the jagged array.

Comment: see also [Declaring a C function to return an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453410/declaring-a-c-function-to-return-an-array), [malloc in C, but use multi-dimensional array syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144132/malloc-in-c-but-use-multi-dimensional-array-syntax/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C doesn't have a true multidimensional array type. You have to either return a jagged array, or return an array of arrays. (Also, since arrays cannot be returned by value; in both cases you have to dynamically allocate the array, and return a pointer to it). [Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453410/declaring-a-c-function-to-return-an-array).

For the array of arrays option, you declare and allocate it like this:

```
Entry (*matrix)[N_CC] = malloc( states * sizeof *matrix );
```

By using this pattern for the argument to malloc, you avoid having to worry about any complicated stuff.

The type of a function to return this pointer is:

```
Entry (*matCreate(FILE *fp))[N_CC];
```

In the calling code you can use the function like this:

```
Entry (*matrix)[N_CC] = matCreate(fp);
bar( matrix[1][2].action );
```

You could use a typedef to make all of this simpler syntax. Personally I prefer not to, as then it is less obvious when array-pointer decay is happening.

Comment: Thank you, I confused myself.  If I may ask one more question, am I still able to access elements at, for example, "ourMat[0][0].action"? I'm getting the error "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector".

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign **malloc** return pointer to Entry **

```
  Entry **matrix;
  matrix= (Entry**)malloc(states * sizeof(Entry *));
  for (i = 0; i < states; i++)
       Entry[i] = malloc(N_CC *   sizeof(Entry));
```